# Ubuntu resource benchmarking

Tags: server, benchmarks

I need to benchmark my Ubuntu server. I need to do it programmatically so I'm looking for some non-GUI application/API for this purpose. I need something that measure my CPU,RAM, HDD ...etc

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really means non-GUI, try `sysbench`. You can install it by run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install sysbench
```

Run `man sysbench` for the man page.